# UIAccessibilityElement TraitAdjustable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiaccessibility

Im creating a container for two frame based accessibility elements which are being drawn using Core Graphics in a custom uiview.

I want the two elements, in this case two cursors, to respond to the one finger slide up and down, so I am using the trait `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable`.

I have implemented the protocol as described in the doc by Apple. I am able to select the two elements but the one finger scroll doesn't seem to be calling `accessibilityIncrement` and `accessibilityDecrement`. Is there something I have missed?

```
-(NSArray *)accessibleElements 
{    
    if (_accessibleElements != nil) {
        return _accessibleElements;
    }

    _accessibleElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //add left cursor
    UIAccessibilityElement *lcursorEl = [[UIAccessibilityElement alloc]
                                            initWithAccessibilityContainer:self];
    lcursorEl.accessibilityFrame = [self convertRect:_lcursorFrame
                                                 toView:nil];
    lcursorEl.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"Left Cursor", nil);
    lcursorEl.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable;
    [_accessibleElements addObject:lcursorEl];

    //add right cursor

    UIAccessibilityElement *rcursorEl = [[UIAccessibilityElement alloc]
                                         initWithAccessibilityContainer:self];
    rcursorEl.accessibilityFrame = [self convertRect:_rcursorFrame
                                              toView:nil];
    rcursorEl.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString(@"Right Cursor", nil);
    //rcursorEl.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable ;
    [_accessibleElements addObject:rcursorEl];

    return _accessibleElements;
}


#pragma mark accessible elements protocol methods

- (NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount
{
    return [[self accessibleElements] count];
}

- (id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return [[self accessibleElements] objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element
{
    return [[self accessibleElements] indexOfObject:element];
}

- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement
{
    return NO;
}

-(void)accessibilityIncrement 
{  
   NSLog(@"Adjusting Inc");
}

-(void)accessibilityDecrement 
{
    NSLog(@"Adjusting dec");
}
```

Comment: I may be mistaken but shouldn't `accessibilityIncrement` and `accessibilityDecrement` be called on the selected elements, not the controller? What happens if you subclass `UIAccessibilityElement` and implements those methods there?

Comment: absolutely spot on I hadn't thought of that, thanks, all working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are setting the adjustable trait on the accessibility elements that you are creating then `accessibilityIncrement` and `accessibilityDecrement` will get called on those elements and not on your controller. That is why you are not seeing any callbacks.

Instead you could subclass `UIAccessibilityElement` and implement the increment and decrement methods there.